# Last Logon Mailboxes Exchange Issues

Tags: powershell, exchange-2010

Let say I have 2 users, so that I need to check the last logon time.

```
Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity "User No 1"
```

Then the **LastLogonTime** property return **NULL**. So I know this user never login to mailbox.

So I using the same command for user no 2

```
Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity "User No 2"
```

Then powershell show warnings like this :

> The user hasn't logged on to mailbox 'User No 2'
>   ('1cf70e56-6580-479b-993f-bc0b46fb23sd'), so there is no data to
>   return. After the user logs on, this warning will no longer appear

So my boss asked, what the different for this user. I believed both of users never login the to Exchange but why only one user return warnings?

How do I can explain to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second mailbox probably hasnt received an email, where as the first email box has. Can you confirm this?

The second error message supposedly happens when there is no emails in the box, where as the first error message happens when there is some form of data or mail in the box

Comment: Yes you are right. Solved my problem. +1

Comment: Make it part of your routine to send each new user a canned email.  ("Hi, welcome to Evil Corp.  Support is 888-328-3425.  Time card software at https://infernal.evil.com/eternal.  Have a Nice Day!")